# Starting the first turn of Turn Based Game Center game

Tags: ios, game-center, gkturnbasedmatch

I have a game I am working on that is turn based between exactly 2 players. I am a bit confused as to how to send the player order if this is the first round and a player hasn't been found yet.

```
- (void)endTurnWithNextParticipants:(NSArray *)nextParticipants turnTimeout:(NSTimeInterval)timeout matchData:(NSData *)matchData completionHandler:(void (^)(NSError *error))completionHandler
```

Answer (score 0):

It is always the local player's turn in the match object returned by `findMatchForRequest: withCompletionHandler:` as specified in the [reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GameKit/Reference/GKTurnBasedMatch_Ref/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/GKTurnBasedMatch/findMatchForRequest%3awithCompletionHandler%3a%20%22reference%22%5C).

> Regardless of how the player is placed in the match, the local player
>   is always the current participant in the returned match.

More specifically to your question, the `matchData` property of that match object will be `nil` in the case where the local player was not matched yet. Since you will assign `matchData` before committing the turn, the other player will see that data instead of `nil`.

By design of the Game Center turn-based match infrastructure, you do not control the player order. If `findMatchForRequest: withCompletionHandler:` finds a match in which someone has already taken a turn, you are second. If it finds an empty match, you are first.

Comment: Thanks for that explanation. The question I still can't wrap my head around is what should my nextParticipants array contain, if this is just a 2 player game and my opponent is nil.

Comment: It is the item in the `participants` property that is not the local player.

Answer (score 0):

This is an old thread, but since I recently struggled with something related this, I thought this might help others who pass through:

Participants are slots in the game, whether occupied or not. Players fill those slots as they are found. The whole "It's always my turn" thing equates to: you are operating with games with a preset number of participants (slots), but those slots may not have been filled yet. This makes it really damn difficult to show info to the users in some cases because you're just getting NULL back from the empty participant fields, and you need to be handle those situations gracefully. On the first turn, subsequent users don't even know they've been invited until each preceding player has taken a turn. Kind of takes the steam out of your gameplay when you take a turn and *then* your invitee declines because they can't play. IMO, the model is only viable for automatch. I don't really like the user experience when inviting friends to a match. But, that's the way it is.

So, for ending a turn, you basically take your match.participants array and move the current (aka local) player to the end of the list. Don't try to edit match.participants directly, that will cause all sorts of flakiness. Instead, make a new array and inject items into in the order you want. I used this code, which I think originally came from the Ray Wenderlich site:

```
    NSMutableArray *nextParticipants = [NSMutableArray new];
    for (GKTurnBasedParticipant *participant in theMatch.participants)
    {
        if ([participant.player.playerID isEqualToString:[GKLocalPlayer localPlayer].playerID])
        {
            [nextParticipants addObject:participant];
        }
        else
        {
            [nextParticipants insertObject:participant atIndex:0];
        }
    }
```

then ended the turn as:

```
    [theMatch endTurnWithNextParticipants:nextParticipants
                              turnTimeout:timeOutSeconds                     
                                matchData:updatedMatchData
                        completionHandler:^(NSError *error)
    {
           ....
    }];
```

This works because all of the participant slots exist from the moment the match is instantiated, regardless of whether players have filled those participant slots or not. Those unfilled slots will be in the "invited" or "matching" state. When one of those slots bubble to the top of the array, making it "their turn" then game center goes looking for the invitee/automatch player to fill the slot and take a turn.